# How do I read the semantic tags from an SRGS .grxml file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, grammar, speech-recognition, semantics

Say I had this simple section from a grammar below:

```
<rule id="WhoAreYou" scope="private">
 <one-of>
  <item>who</item>
  <item>what</item>
 </one-of>
  <item>
    are
    you
  </item>
 <tag>1000</tag>
</rule>
```

How would I appropriately return the "1000" from the tag? I am using the System.Speech library and I am trying to return this value to a method using SpeechRecognizedEventArgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just figured it out. I was using e.Result.Semantics.Value.ToString() which was returning the exact same text as was spoken. I realized I had set tag-format="semantics-ms/1.0" when setting it to tag-format="semantics/1.0" interpreted the tag as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that section of xml in a string, you could parse the string into an LINQ to XML [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `XDocument.Parse(string)` and use that to fetch the value. Read up on LINQ to XML [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :)

Comment: Josh is not referring to the actual value between the tag elements (i.e the value 1000); he is referring to what the VoiceXML browser returns as a result of speech input. The question was not phrased very well. It was not so much a C#/XML question as it is which shadow variable to use to get the results he wanted.